# Viewing h264 stream over TCP

Tags: python, stream, video-streaming, h.264

I have a small wifi based FPV camera for a drone. I've managed to get it to the point where I can download and save an h264 file using python.

```
TCP_IP = '193.168.0.1'
TCP_PORT = 6200
BUFFER_SIZE = 2056

f = open('stream.h264', 'wb')
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect((TCP_IP,TCP_PORT))
while True:
    data = sock.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
    f.write(data)
    print("Writing")
sock.close()
f.close()
```

What I've been trying to do for a while now is play the stream. I've found the stream, I can download it and save it, but now I want to open it live.
I've tried using VLC's 'open network stream' with a variety of options, but none of them seemed to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I successfully output to mplayer using

`data = sock.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
 sys.stdout.buffer.write(data)`

and then having mplayer pipe the input

`python cam.py - | mplayer -fps 20 -nosound -vc ffh264 -noidx -mc 0 -`

Comment: Hello! I'm trying to read packets from a h.264 stream, and stumbled upon your response. Unfortunately, using "sys.stdout.buffer.write" resulted in an error: "AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'buffer'". Any advice?

Comment: I barely remember this, but you need the data from your script going to the shell, if you just run a python script from bash, you should be able to write to the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

It is a simple way, yes: send H.264 NALU stream (you put 0,0,0,1 prefix before each nal unit and it is ok).

If you want something more cool, then you can add packing to RTP and send it via multicast. It will be rather simple to code and easy to read.