# How to replicate C# .read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length) in Python

Tags: c#, python, soap, io

Yesterday I asked a similar question about the filestream method, [What is the Python equivalent to FileStream in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41841016/what-is-the-python-equivalent-to-filestream-in-c]), but I now realize I should have probably been asking about the .read function instead.

For context I am trying to consume a streamed response from a soap API, which should output a CSV file. The response outputs a string coded in base 64, which I do not know what to do with. Also the api documentation says that the response must be read to a destination buffer-by-buffer.

Here is the context in the code. The code was provided by the api's documentation:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[4000];
bool endOfStream = false;
int bytesRead = 0;
using (FileStream localFileStream = new FileStream(destinationPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
   using (Stream remoteStream = client.DownloadFile(jobId, chkFormatAsXml.Unchecked))
   {
     while (!endOfStream)
     {
         bytesRead = remoteStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
         if (bytesRead > 0)
         {
              localFileStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
              totalBytes += bytesRead;
         }
         else
         {
              endOfStream = true;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, even if it is just to point me in the right direction, as I am very lost now. I also, had another question referencing the same problem today as well. [Write Streamed Response(file-like object) to CSV file Byte by Byte in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41861602/write-streamed-responsefile-like-object-to-csv-file-byte-by-byte-in-python)

Comment: Just do `remoteStream.read(n)`, where `n` is how much you want to read.

Comment: Thanks, Would you know how I could read a single buffer at a time?

Comment: What is a "buffer"? Do you know its size? If you do, just read that many bytes.

Comment: Good q, looking at the code it looks like the buffer is created by:        `byte[] buffer = new byte[4000]`

Comment: Since you know the size in C# `buffer.Length`, there must be a way to find it in Python, too. So, `read(4000)`.

Comment: So should `len(openfile.read(4000))` be the equivalent of  `bytesRead = remoteStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)` as far as you know? Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Affirmative. It will be.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Would you know the python equivalent of `localFileStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)`or at least be able to briefly describe what the `bytes[4000]` variable means in the context of the Write function? Your help has been greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `bytesread = len(openfile.read(4000))` is the correct way to replicate `bytesRead = remoteStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);`

Thanks DYZ